# Can/should ChromeDriver be installed on the same PATH (usr/bin) as Python, easy_install, etc.?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, chrome

The Selenium WebDriver for Python video I'm watching instructs me to copy ChromeDriver to `/usr/local/bin`. When I view my `$PATH`, I can see `/usr/local/bin`, but if I `cd` to `/usr/local/bin` it says the directory does not exist.

```
echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

cd /usr/local/bin
-bash: cd: /usr/local/bin: Not a directory
```

Python came pre-installed in OS 10.9.5 and it's in `/usr/bin`. Should I just copy ChromeDriver to `/usr/bin`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put ChromeDriver wherever you like if you specify the path:

```
chromedriver_path = "<path_to_chromedriver>"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path)
```

It's really up to you if you want in `usr/local/bin` or elsewhere.